# open cv: add with numpy with maximum value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray which represents a rgb color:

```
upper = np.array([100,50,255], dtype="uint8")
```

When I increment it:

```
upper += 1
```

It gives me: `[101  51  0]`

I understand that, but I don't want the wrapping around the 0-255 range boundaries.

Is there a numpy way (not a manual loop) to say: increment each value of the array, unless the value is 255 (in which case do nothing)?

Comment: `np.add(a,1, out=a, where=a<255)`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.